Git clone stuck and timeout
When i try to git clone any repository (example here from https://github.com/zpqrtbnk/test-repo.git) it get stuck at "cloning into ..."
here is the log output ->
i don't have the problem on other machine connected to the same network/proxy
GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE_CURL_NO_DATA=1 GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1 git clone --verbose --progress https://github.com/zpqrtbnk/test-repo.git
16:05:21.465186 git.c:444               trace: built-in: git clone --verbose --progress https://github.com/zpqrtbnk/test-repo.git
Clonage dans 'test-repo'...
16:05:21.467186 run-command.c:664       trace: run_command: git remote-https origin https://github.com/zpqrtbnk/test-repo.git
16:05:21.468518 git.c:730               trace: exec: git-remote-https origin https://github.com/zpqrtbnk/test-repo.git
16:05:21.468550 run-command.c:664       trace: run_command: git-remote-https origin https://github.com/zpqrtbnk/test-repo.git
16:05:21.474931 http.c:756              == Info: Couldn't find host github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
16:05:21.476526 http.c:756              == Info:   Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
16:05:21.477173 http.c:756              == Info: Connected to proxy.xxx (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 8080 (#0)
16:05:21.477184 http.c:756              == Info: allocate connect buffer!
16:05:21.477191 http.c:756              == Info: Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to github.com:443
16:05:21.477225 http.c:703              => Send header, 0000000111 bytes (0x0000006f)
16:05:21.477233 http.c:715              => Send header: CONNECT github.com:443 HTTP/1.1
16:05:21.477236 http.c:715              => Send header: Host: github.com:443
16:05:21.477242 http.c:715              => Send header: User-Agent: git/2.30.2
16:05:21.477249 http.c:715              => Send header: Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
16:05:21.477255 http.c:715              => Send header:
16:05:21.514562 http.c:703              <= Recv header, 0000000037 bytes (0x00000025)
16:05:21.514577 http.c:715              <= Recv header: HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
16:05:21.514586 http.c:703              <= Recv header, 0000000002 bytes (0x00000002)
16:05:21.514590 http.c:715              <= Recv header:
16:05:21.514595 http.c:756              == Info: Proxy replied 200 to CONNECT request
16:05:21.514598 http.c:756              == Info: CONNECT phase completed!
16:05:21.549673 http.c:756              == Info: found 384 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
16:05:21.549740 http.c:756              == Info: ALPN, offering h2
16:05:21.549748 http.c:756              == Info: ALPN, offering http/1.1

and then 10m later i got
"error: git-remote-https died of signal 8"
(timeout i guess)
there is no errors visible, so i'm not sure what to do
any suggestion ?

Does your proxy have any logs?
